# Отразить вектор от прямой

Tags: unity3d, vector, геометрия, math, векторы

Есть вектор `a` направленный под углом `α` к оси абсцисс.
Также есть прямая под углом `β` к оси абсцисс.

---

[image: Отражение вектора от прямой]

Необходимо отразить вектор `a` от прямой и получить результирующий вектор `b`.

Comment: Хорошая задачка, хотя и не имеет прямого отношения к программированию. Приступайте.

Comment: `gamma = 2*betta - alpha = 99.77`, `b = (cos(gamma), sin(gamma))`

Comment: @Igor, нужно было в игру небольшую добавить стенку, которая отражала бы выстрелы. Первое что пришло в голову - спросить на StackOverflow.

Comment: Угол падения равен углу отражения?

Comment: @ilyaplot, да, разумеется

Comment: если игра и на юнити, так может использовать их методы? типа https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html

Comment: @Sithell в реальном мире это не так :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо! Напишите как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Unity для отражения от плоскости можно воспользоваться **[Vector3.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html)** - отражает вектор с плоскости, определенной некой нормалью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример из документации:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform originalObject;
    public Transform reflectedObject;
    void Update() {
        reflectedObject.position = Vector3.Reflect(originalObject.position, Vector3.right);
    }
}
```

---

Не уверен, но возможно еще как вариант взглянуть на физику и возможность устанавливать влияние физики материала на элемент (например отскок)

пара видео об этом с офф. сайта unity:
https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/bouncing-ball
https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/bouncing-sliding-2d?playlist=17120

Answer (score 1):

Задача чисто векторная, то есть не привязанная к конкретным координатам точек, но я для наглядности буду ссылаться на конкретные точки на изображении.

1. Строим перпендикуляр к прямой KB (к "стенке"), проходящий через точку B.
2. Отражаем точку A относительно перпендикуляра, т.е. например строим ортогональную проекцию точки A на перпендикуляр. Точка проекции лежит посередине между A и ее отражением.
3. Это отражение и есть точка C.

А если через тригонометрию, то понятно, что надо просто сместить точку A вдоль вектора KB на расстояние `2 * |a| * cos (β - α)`.

Comment: непонятно откуда формула для расстояния ? посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ через векторы

Comment: @ampawd: А что именно непонятно? Угол KBA равен `β - α`. Значит длина проекции вектора AB на прямую KB равна `|a| * cos (β - α)`. В удвоенном виде это расстояние и есть то расстояние, на которое нам надо перенести точку A в направлении KB, чтобы получить точку C.

Comment: Альтернативно вы можете получить тот же результат применив формулу длины основания AC равнобедренного треугольника ABC, перед этим вычислив угол B (т.е. фактически применив теорему косинусов к треугольнику ABC).

Answer (score 1):

так как уже отметили, что задача чисто векторная, потому и предложу соответствующее решение, которое, кстати говоря объясняет предположительную реализацию метода `Vector3.Reflect` в юнити.

Отражённый вектор `b` вычисляется следующим образом

`1. b = a - 2*dot(a, n)*n`

где `n` нормализованный вектор нормали к прямой, который, в вашем случае можно найти, например, так:

`n = (B.x - ||a||*cos(alpha), B.y - ||a||*sin(alpha))`

а так как `dot(a, n)*n` это проекция вектора `a` на нормаль с одной стороны и проекция вектора `b` на нормаль `n` c другой, то в конечном итоге по свойству векторного сложения получаем, что

`a + b = 2*dot(a, n)*n` а это в свою очередь даёт формулу 1.

вот и всё

Comment: @AnT опечатка )) это строка не нужна

Comment: @AnT хотел вместо `||a||` написать `r` и забыл, смысл не меняется

Comment: Пожалуй, лучше даже не уточнять единичность нормали - в общем виде `b=a-n*(2*dot(a,n)/dot(n,n)))`. Обычно вектора какие-то, не нормированные, а в запись общем виде не нуждается в корне.